# Highest and lowest average C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I've recently tried to make a program which calculates the highest test scores, lowest test and averages of all test scores.

So far my program has been able to do all that; however, I then tried to see if I can calculate the highest of all the AVERAGES, and lowest of all the AVERAGES, and I can't figure it out.

I have tried a lot of things and nothing has worked so far. Right now all I get is all the test scores, their averages, the highest test scores, and lowest, but not the highest and lowest of the averages. What can I do to better figure this out?

Any tips, advice is greatly appreciated. I'll lay out below what I have done that works so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
const int amount = 3;
int count;
int Total = 0;
int TestScore1[amount], TestScore2 [amount], TestScore3 [amount];
double average[amount];

int main()
{
    for(int count = 0; count < amount; count++)

    {
        cout<<"Enter Test Score " << (count + 1) << ": " <<endl;
        cin>> TestScore1[count];
        cin>>TestScore2[count];
        cin>>TestScore3[count];
    }

    cout<<"Your test result are: \n Test 1: Test 2: Test 3: Average: "<<endl;
    for(int count = 0; count < amount; count++)

    {
        Total = 0;
        double average = 0;

        Total += TestScore1[count];
        Total += TestScore2[count];
        Total += TestScore3[count];
        average = Total / amount;
        cout <<  "   " << TestScore1[count]
        << " \t" << TestScore2[count]
        <<" \t "<< TestScore3[count] <<"\t"  << average <<endl;


    }

    double highest = TestScore1[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {
        if(TestScore1[count] > highest)
        highest = TestScore1[count];
    }

    cout<<"Test 1 Highest: " <<highest <<endl;


    double highest2 = TestScore2[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {

        if(TestScore2[count] > highest)
        highest2 = TestScore2[count];

    }
    cout<<"Test 2 Highest: " <<highest2 <<endl;

    double highest3 = TestScore3[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {

    if(TestScore3[count] > highest)
        highest3 = TestScore3[count];

    }
    cout<<"Test 3 Highest: " <<highest3 <<endl;

    double Lowest = TestScore1[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {
        if(TestScore1[count] < Lowest)
        Lowest = TestScore1[count];
    }

    cout<<"Test 1 Lowest: " <<Lowest <<endl;


    double Lowest2 = TestScore2[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {

        if(TestScore2[count] < Lowest2)
        Lowest2 = TestScore2[count];

    }
    cout<<"Test 2 Lowest: " <<Lowest2 <<endl;

    double Lowest3 = TestScore3[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {

        if(TestScore3[count] < Lowest3)
        Lowest3 = TestScore3[count];

    }
    cout<<"Test 3 Lowest: " <<Lowest3 <<endl;



}
```

Comment: `double average = 0;` in your loop "hides" the declared array of averages above.  So, you're never storing the averages outside of that loop.

Comment: Nothing seems to write to `average[count]` at all, although you do have a scalar `double average` hiding the array name inside one loop. Where did you _expect_ the array of averages to be populated if you didn't write any code to do that?

Comment: @chad you're correct. That worked. Thanks.

Comment: As a rule, please compile with warning enabled. Pretty sure the compiler would have told you that immediately...

Comment: and use std::vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop second, you declare a variable called average

```
double average = 0;
```

Then you assign the average value to it. This variable hides the array you declared outside also called average. You need to remove this variable declaration from the program and write to the array directly using

```
average[count] = Total / amount;
```

This way the average values are actually stored and can be accessed later on.